# How to get all values from querySelectorAll and pass to URL in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send a dynamic TD of table which returned 3 values..I am using the line below to submit the value...I want to be able to pass all three values to a URL LIKE THIS 778, 44, 45

```js
function JSalert() {

  // var valueID = document.getElementById('idweek1').innerHTML

  var data = document.querySelectorAll('[name=idweek1]');

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    theids =  data[i].className + " " + data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    window.location = 'http://localhost/bcwater/public/submitinvestment/'+value8+'/'+theids;

  }

}
```

```html
<td id="idweek1" name="idweek1">778</td>      
<td id="idweek1" name="idweek1">44</td>  
<td id="idweek1" name="idweek1">55</td>
```

Comment: Changing the location belongs outside of the loop, not inside of it. And you need to actually concatenate those values into one, right now you are simply overwriting `theids ` in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it done using the method below

```
 var array_of_name = [];
          var elements_arr = document.getElementsByClassName("idweek1");
          for (var i in elements_arr) {
              array_of_name.push(elements_arr[i].innerHTML);
          }
          console.log("TRGY",array_of_name);

So when i pass the variable to the URL it works fine
 window.location = 'http://localhost/bcwater/public/submitinvestment/'+value8+'/'+array_of_name;
```

Comment: You should mention the fact that you added `.idweek1` as a class to each `<td>`. Moreover, you should remove the #id or replace the #id with a unique #id for each `<td>` because it's invalid HTML to have duplicated #ids. All browsers assume that there's only one instance of any given #id on a webpage, thus once the browser finds said #id, it stops searching which means any element with the same #id after the first one will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Basically nothing with your code, except it's missing `<table>` & `<tbody>` elements.

```js
var data = document.querySelectorAll('[name=idweek1]');
var value8 = 88888888;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  id =  data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  console.log(id);
  console.log('http://localhost/bcwater/public/submitinvestment/' + value8 + '/' + id);
}
  // window.location.href = 'http://localhost/bcwater/public/submitinvestment/' + value8 + '/' + id;
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="idweek1" name="idweek1">778</td>
      <td id="idweek1" name="idweek1">44</td>
      <td id="idweek1" name="idweek1">55</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```